# tick up order number

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a command in one of my bots; I want to add a feature to it where it ticks up the order number.

My command code:

```
var baseOrderNumber = '1'
    const invite = await message.channel.createInvite()
    if(cmd === `${prefix}order`){
        baseOrderNumber++;
    orderEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    orderIcon = message.guild.iconURL
    orderEmbed.setTitle("New Order")
    orderEmbed.setColor("#FF2D00")
    orderEmbed.addField("Order Number", baseOrderNumber)
    orderEmbed.addField("Order", args, arg2)
    orderEmbed.addField("Customer", message.author)
    orderEmbed.addField("Server Invite", invite)
    
    
     bot.channels.cache.get('723838675489914891').send(orderEmbed)     
    }
```

But when I run the command to test it; the order number always stays on 1, anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: I figured it out; instead of making it a var; I put it as a

```
let baseOrderNumber = 1;
```

just above the first starting bit of code of the bot.

Comment: How are you running the command? Where do you tell us what `prefix` is?  Your question lacks important details.

Comment: I think the problem is the `baseOrderNumber` is reset everything this snippet is called, so it always stays at 1. You could do it the dirty way and make it a global variable in the root of your app, or use some kind of state management/persistence.